# Optimize query through the order of columns in index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I had a table that is holding a domain and id
the query is

```
    select distinct domain 
    from user 
    where id = '1'
```

the index is using the order `idx_domain_id` is faster than `idx_id_domain`

if the order of the execution is

> (FROM clause,WHERE clause,GROUP BY clause,HAVING clause,SELECT
>   clause,ORDER BY clause)

then the query should be faster if it use the sorted `where` columns than the `select` one.

- at 15:00 to 17:00 it show the same query i am working on
  https://serversforhackers.com/laravel-perf/mysql-indexing-three

the table has a 4.6 million row.

time using idx_domain_id
[image: time using idx_domain_id]

time after change the order
[image: time after change the order]

Comment: `id='1'` MySQL hint if the id column datatype is a INT query it as a INT not a VARCHAR|CHAR.. MySQL auto typecasting can mess things up and the optimizer might be unable to use indexing

Comment: Provide table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`) and a explain (`EXPLAIN <query>`).. Ideally for this query you should have a (extra) covering `index(id, first_name)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland i included a video s url had the same query.

Comment: Is the id column primary key?

Comment: @SalmanA yes id is the primary key

Comment: `idx_domain_id` does not say anything.  Please show the definition of the index(es).

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select distinct first_name 
from user 
where id = '1';
```

You are observing that `user(first_name, id)` is faster than `user(id, firstname)`.

Why might this be the case?  First, this could simply be an artifact of how your are doing the timing.  If your table is really small (i.e. the data fits on a single data page), then indexes are generally not very useful for improving performance.

Second, if you are only running the queries once, then the first time you run the query, you might have a "cold cache".  The second time, the data is already stored in memory, so it runs faster.

Other issues can come up as well.  You don't specify what the timings are.  Small differences can be due to noise and might be meaningless.

You don't provide enough information to give a more definitive explanation.  That would include:

- Repeated timings run on cold caches.
- Size information on the table and the number of matching rows.
- Layout information, particularly the type of `id`.
- Explain plans for the two queries.

Comment: @Gordan thanks alot for your reply, so the query can't be predictable for many of the cases i am try to get a solid knowledge to ensure that the order of the index i am using is the best for the query (I added a images for the timing in the question)

Comment: On a production system, "warm cache" is the norm.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct domain 
from user 
where id = '1'
```

Since `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, there is at most *one* row involved.  Hence, the keyword `DISTINCT` is useless.

And the most useful index is what you already have, `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  It will drill down the BTree to find `id='1'` and deliver the value of `domain` that is sitting right there.

On the other hand, consider

```
select distinct domain 
from user 
where something_else = '1'
```

*Now*, the obvious index is `INDEX(something_else, domain)`.  This is optimal for the `WHERE` clause, and it is "covering" (meaning that all the columns needed by the query exist in the index).  Swapping the columns in the index will be slower.  Meanwhile, since there could be multiple rows, `DISTINCT` means something.  However, it is not the logical thing to use.

Concerning your title question (order of columns):  The `=` columns in the `WHERE` clause should come *first*.  (More details in the link below.)

`DISTINCT` means to gather all the rows, then de-duplicate them.  Why go to that much effort when this gives the same answer:

```
select  domain 
from user 
where something_else = '1'
LIMIT 1
```

This hits only one row, not all the 1s.

Read my [*Indexing Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

(And, yes, Gordon has a lot of good points.)